# % of specific value in column over # of rows in that column

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have output data from a query such as

```
ID | Type | Date
321   Car    2/2/12
443   Truck  4/4/21
444   Car    4/3/21
639   Truck  3/5/21
211   Car    3/4/21
```

How can I add an outer query so I can calculate grouped by the Type column the % for each value in that column?

```
Desired Output:

Type  |  %
Car     .6
Truck   .4
```

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check the updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use aggregation and division:

```
select type,
       count(*) * 1.0 / sum(count(*)) over () as ratio
from t
group by type;
```

You don't need a subquery of any sort to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following answer.

```
SELECT T.Type, (COUNT(T.Type)*1.0)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableName)[%]
FROM TableName T
GROUP BY T.Type
```

If it throwing any error, then please let me know.

**Output:**

```
Type    %
Car     0.600000000000
Truck   0.400000000000
```

You can use the subquery in the `CTE`.

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(SELECT * FROM TableName)
SELECT T.Type, (COUNT(T.Type)*1.0)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CTE)[%]
FROM CTE T
GROUP BY T.Type
```

This will also give you the same result.

Comment: My current data set I showed was from an existing query - so if this is a subquery how can I structure your answer?

Comment: to keep it simple lets say select * from TableName gives me my original data set

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ratio_to_report` for this as well:

```sql
select
    type,
    sum(ratio)
from (select type,
             ratio_to_report(1) over () as ratio
         from ([your subquery]))
group by type;
```

**Returns**:

```
+-----+----------+
|TYPE |SUM(RATIO)|
+-----+----------+
|Car  |0.600000  |
|Truck|0.400000  |
+-----+----------+
```